# Outlook VBA broken by read receipts

Tags: vba, outlook

I have this code that runs on incoming messages. It strips the attachment then forwards the email to a different address. It's being broken by read receipts because I guess they don't count as a MailItem.

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
Dim varEntryID As Variant

For Each varEntryID In Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
    Dim objOriginalItem As MailItem
    Set objOriginalItem = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetItemFromID(varEntryID)
    Dim objForwardedItem As MailItem
    Set objForwardedItem = objOriginalItem.Forward

    Do Until objForwardedItem.Attachments.Count = 0
        objForwardedItem.Attachments.Remove (1)
    Loop

    objForwardedItem.DeleteAfterSubmit = True
    objForwardedItem.To = "LoanPostClosing@domain.com"
    objForwardedItem.Send
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to treat the new item as a generic Object and check the Class property. See below.

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
Dim varEntryID As Variant

For Each varEntryID In Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
    Dim objOriginalItem As Object
    Set objOriginalItem = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetItemFromID(varEntryID)
    if objOriginalItem.Class = 43 Then
      Dim objForwardedItem As MailItem
      Set objForwardedItem = objOriginalItem.Forward

      Do Until objForwardedItem.Attachments.Count = 0
          objForwardedItem.Attachments.Remove (1)
      Loop

      objForwardedItem.DeleteAfterSubmit = True
      objForwardedItem.To = "LoanPostClosing@yourcnb.com"
      objForwardedItem.Send
   End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I thought this was going to work, but for some reason it keeps stopping with an error. It highlights the Next at the end of the code and says Next without For. Any ideas?

Comment: I was just using the code you submitted as an answer here. When I saw that it was messing up, I just temporarily reverted to the code in my question but it still breaks to read receipts.

Comment: The code above compiles just fine for me. Still, what is your code?